# .NET 3.5 SP1 as a requirement (or should I try for 3.5 w/o SP1)?

Tags: .net, wpf

We're creating a WPF custom control targeted at .NET 3.5. It is very compelling to use StringFormat property in bindings, but this was only added in SP1.

So the question is: how many potential users will we be cutting off by changing the requirement from .NET 3.5 to .NET 3.5 SP1? Or is it safe to assume that more or less every user who has .NET 3.5 already has SP1 (or will have it in the not so distant future)?

Your opinions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large corporations, SP1 might still be slow to deploy to desktops - simply that it is a fair amount of testing etc, and unless you've got a good reason to do it, you'd be tempted not to.

And for individuals - it can be a big download unless you've got a fat pipe (which not everyone does).

For example, at my work we've deployed to the web-servers (since they need it), but not to user desktops. If I had a need to push SP1 I would, but I don't see much point until then.

You might also want to see if your code would run on Client Profile? This is then only a <30MB install away... although I've never actually seen anyone use Client Profile in anger (if you're going to have to do a deployment, heck: push the big one...).

So it really depends: who are the users of this app? Can you strong-arm them to upgrade? Or at least "encourage" them ;-p

Comment: It's not an app, it's a control. The "users" of this control would be developers of other WPF apps. So I wont have direct control of end-user behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I think we'll go for a little more work but no SP1 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying your WPF application? If by installer then can you not just add SP1 as a prerequisite and let the installer sort the rest out?

You should be able to bundle SP1 with your installer (if you're sending out traditional media), or allow it to be downloaded.

Comment: It's not an application, it's a control. The "users" of this control would be developers of other WPF apps. So I wont have direct control of end-user behavior/experience.

Comment: If your customers are other developers, and they're already using the latest version of .NET then I think it's pretty reasonable to expect them to have SP1 installed.

Answer (score 0):

.net 3.5 sp1 will be on Windows Updates for everyone with .net installed, so unless it's a big company with very slow deployment strategies I would say it shouldn't be a problem.

Also, in such a comapny with those deployment policies I wouldn't expect to find .net 3.5 at all.

I personally started selling a WPF application almost the moment .net 3.0 was released, everyone is always talking about the big download but I've never got a complaint about it from a real potential user, only from other developers or IT people in forums. (if your target audience has a lot of people still using dial-up then you have different problems, and probably no .net 3.5 either)